# Different types of options for blocking Packet Using Snort

Tags: snort

What are the differences between drop , reject , sdrop snort rule actions and react option in the rule header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation lists the following actions and their effect:

- **drop** block and log the packet
- **reject** block the packet, log it, and then send a TCP reset if the protocol is TCP or an ICMP port unreachable message if the protocol is UDP.
- **sdrop** block the packet but do not log it.

These can be found on the documentation page [Snort Rule Headers](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node29.html)

**react** whose documentation can be found [here](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node26.html#SECTION003114000000000000000) is a rule option keyword that allows you to first send a html page back before resetting the session.

As per the documentation this must be enabled when building snort with the following option:

`./configure --enable-react / -DENABLE_REACT`